# Multiple MySQL Workbench Synchronizing issues

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I just started using MySQL Workbench and I'm experiencing multiple issues while Synchronizing.

I modelled the schema using Workbench and Forward Engineered it and ran it successfully in the database server. Later edited a Trigger and tried to synchronise it with the database server

So I went to `Database -> Synchronize Model...`

[image]

I have only edited one trigger(just added `+1` to an already existing variable in the Trigger) but as you can see it shows that all the tables must be changed/updated(with a little yellow exclamation mark). **It shouldn't be right?**

And when I click `continue`, I noticed in the generated script that it is deleting foreign keys and again adding them.
[image]

And when I clicked on `Execute`, it is showing an error:

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Default Collation' at line 1
```

[image]

Also, it adds `DEFAULT COLLATE Default Collation` for all `ALTER` statements for schemas and tables, which is causing `error 1064`

```
ALTER SCHEMA `myschema`  DEFAULT COLLATE Default Collation ;

.....
.....

.....

ALTER TABLE `table1` 
COLLATE = Default Collation ;

ALTER TABLE `table2` 
COLLATE = Default Collation ;

ALTER TABLE `table3` 
COLLATE = Default Collation ;
....
....
....
....
```

---

MySQL Community Edition: 8.0.19

MySQL Workbench: 8.0.19

macOS: Catalina 10.15.3

I've researched on other SO posts about `error: 1064` and many suggested to change the version. So, I've also changed the MySQL version in Workbench `Model -> Model Options... -> MySQL -> Target MySQL Version: 8.0.19` but still the error exists.
[image]

Am I missing something or doing it wrong?

I tried (the other way around) to synchronize model(as destination) with the database server( as source) to make sure at least the database server is as expected. So, when I did that, all the foreign keys are deleted in the EER Diagram.

I checked on the database server are there even foreign keys present using this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102374) and everything is fine on the server.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for the dba forum

Comment: @Strawberry Should I delete this and post in dba or can a moderator transfer it?

Comment: Leave it here for now. Mention in your new question that you've already asked the same thing here, and I suspect someone will take the approprate action if they think it's necessary.

Comment: Have you got anything? I just spent 8hrs without sleep with this issue but no progress. I need some more info about your last method. So, instead of keeping the arrow from `left to right`(Green), you changed that to `right to left`(Yellow) and when you synchronized, all the foreign keys are deleted from your EER? But again you have all the foreign keys in the database server?

Comment: @SkrewEverything Yes, that's right. If you find anything, please don't forget to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether it's supposed to do like this or just a hack but the thing is, I got what I want for now atleast.

I used trail and error. So, I don't know why or how but it works.

Open the workbench, get the schema from the database server, edit the schema in your workbench and synchronize. This way even if someone changed on the server, you get the latest version of the schema.

Go to `Database -> Reverse Engineer`. It creates EER diagram from your database server schema.

Once you get the EER diagram generated, try to edit your changes and go to `Database -> Synchronize Model..`. Now you only have the **yellow exclamation mark** before a table name which you have modified(instead of before all the tables as you said)

Also when I did this, there are no `DEFAULT COLLATE Default Collation` lines or foreign keys deletion and addition lines in the final script. The final script only contained which is required.

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: It is strange how buggy it is while being powerful. Anyway thanks it worked for me.